# How do I flatten params passed to recur?

Tags: loops, clojure

I'm trying to learn about `loop/recur`. I wanted to pass the return vector from a function back to the loop and I've tried something like this:

```
(defn foo [x y] 
  [(dec x) y])

(loop [x 3 y 4]
  (if (> x 0)
    (do
      (prn x y)
      (recur (foo x y)))))
```

That gives:

```
1. Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
   Mismatched argument count to recur, expected: 2 args, got: 1
```

Now I can change the loop parameters to this other form which works:

```
(defn foo [x y] 
  [(dec x) y])

(loop [[x y] [3 4]]
  (if (> x 0)
    (do
      (prn x y)
      (recur (foo x y)))))
```

I'd like to know if there's any way I could change the first code to leave the `(loop [x 3 y 4] ...)` but change the arguments passed to `recur` somehow. I guess I need something like the `apply` function, but I couldn't get that to work with `recur`, because `recur` is not a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no easy way around it.  `recur` is a [special
form](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#recur) and Clojures
way around the JVM not having easy access to TCO.

Therefor you can not use `apply` here (which would be a solution to call
a function with arguments from a list).

So you have to hold on to the result of `foo` and then `recur` with
those.  Note beside: `if` with just one branch is just `when`.

```clj
(defn foo [x y] 
  [(dec x) y])

(loop [x 3 y 4]
  (when (> x 0)
    (prn x y)
    (let [[x' y'] (foo x y)] 
      (recur x' y'))))
```

If your domain here really is `[x y]` (e.g. coordinates) my suggestion
would be to build your functions around that and don't jump between
sometimes using a vector and sometimes passing x/y.

Answer (score 2):

you could also make up a simple macro for that purpose.. maybe like this (which is basically a macro rewrite of your vectorized params variant):

```
(defmacro loop1 [bindings & body]
  (let [left-side (vec (take-nth 2 bindings))
        right-side (vec (take-nth 2 (rest bindings)))]
    `(loop [~left-side ~right-side]
       ~@body)))

(loop1 [x 3 y 4]
       (if (> x 0)
         (do
           (prn x y)
           (recur (foo x y)))))

;;=> 3 4
;;   2 4
;;   1 4
nil
```

so, if you have repetitive usage pattern alike that, this macro could be a nice utility.

Comment: I would consider it in poor taste to use this macro. It saves very little typing (just two pairs of `[]`), doesn't introduce any powerful new concepts, and makes it easier to be confused by what the function is doing, because it looks so close to a built-in `loop` but does something dubtly different.

Comment: @amalloy,i would disagree: the point is not to reduce the typing, but to make the facility which is a bit closer to the specific programmer's mental model. As for me,, i wouldn't use this one, since i'm ok with destructuring. But i can't deny the possibility someone would. Agree about the confusing naming though